# Eric Martin's Simple Modal- resizing the modal to contain a loaded image

Tags: php, jquery

I have this page that uses Eric Martin's simpleModal jQuery plugin:
http://www.runninghead.com/portfolio.php?image_to_display=0
Trouble is the images aren't contained by the modal (click on an image thumbnail to open the modal).
I have the sizes of the images (thanks to some PHP) so could resize after load, but I want to get the plugin to behave itself without any hacks.
If I go the hack route I may be be missing an error in my coding that'll cause me problems later!

Answer (score 0):

The plugin gives the simplemodal-container a height of 400px. You might want to read the plugin page for this:

http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/

The page explains you can give options to the instance of simplemodal.

here is an awnser which might help you aswell.

[Simplemodal Scroll Bar and Close Image Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5032490/simplemodal-scroll-bar-and-close-image-issue)

Comment: Thanks Meneer- I've read the plugin page but it's not clear to me how it relates to my implementation of the plugin.

Comment: Here:
`function generate_modal_div(arg_1_image, arg_2_title) {
        $('<img src="' + arg_1_image + '"/>');// preload image- does not remedy
        $('#basic-modal-content').html('<img src="' + arg_1_image + '" alt="thumbnail"/>' + '<p>' + arg_2_title + '</p>' + '<a class="prev browse left"></a><a class="next browse right"></a></div>');
    };`